# MongoDB array to string

Tags: php, arrays, string, mongodb

I am trying to assign an element of an array to a string that can be printed out on a webpage. Right now, the MongoDB data looks like:

`> db.test1.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55de668b4ac1fc9e75552db0"),
    "name" : "john",
    "friends" : {
        "best" : "rebecca",
        "acquaintance" : "steve"
    }
}`

After I do the query, I use this PHP code to display my results on a webpage:

`foreach ($result as $result)
    {
      echo sprintf("Name: %s, Best Friend: %s", $result['name'], 
        $result['friends.best']);
    }
}`

However when I do this, nothing shows up after Best Friend and I get an error:

`Notice: Undefined index: friends.best on line 27`
.

What syntax should I use to be able to access the friends.best element?

Comment: "dot notation" is for queries to MongoDB. Once the object is returned to PHP it is a PHP object. So `$result['friends']['best']`

Comment: Simply change `$result['friends.best']` to `$result['friends']['best']`

Comment: Thank you both so much! I didn't realize the dot notation was only for MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($result as $result)
    {
      echo sprintf("Name: %s, Best Friend: %s", $result['name'], 
      $result['friends']['best']);
    }
}
```